# Golang how to type json HTTP Response Body

Tags: json, go, http, types

I have a nested JSON object being sent in a request body, http protocol. One of the keys of the JSON field starts with an underscore '_'.  How can I export the field? Example:

```
type TopologyGateway struct {
    _my_property string `json:"_my_property"`
}
```

Gives the following error:
`struct field _my_property has json tag but is not exported`

Any help would be more than appreciated!

Tried digging through other stack overflows and articles, no luck.

Comment: Can you add more details like how you are sending the JSON object?  The issue might be there.

Comment: https://go.dev/ref/spec#Exported_identifiers identifiers beginning with `_` are not exported.  The name of the identifier is not coupled to the json representation; the `json` tag handles that.  Just name it `My_property` or whatever and it will work

Comment: Thanks @erik258. I was hoping not to make any name changes, changing the property name is not very feasible and will require a lot of downstream work.

Comment: It can't be that much downstream work - it's not exported to any other packages. 
If a bunch of in-package stuff uses a different  `_my_property` identifier then yes, that's a mess.  But if this is the only use of `_my_property` you should be able to change it everywhere with a quick `sed` invocation

Answer (score 1):

U can

```golang
type SomeStruct struct {
  MyField string `json:"<_>SomeFiled"`
}
```

Don't use _ for naming ur field \ variables etc.

> variable and field names beginning with an underscore _ are treated as unexported (private) by convention